# In Swift / UIKit, how do you generalize a "base" class of UIView to other view types, given that you can't compose much in the various UIView types

Tags: swift, inheritance, composition

Say I have

```
class Plastic: UIView, SomeProto {
  override something {
    blah
  }
  override func layoutSubviews() {
    blah
  }
}
```

I then have various custom views `GreenPlastic: Plastic` , `YellowPlastic: Plastic` etc.

I want to do exactly the same thing for stack views.

Currently I use copy-paste engineering:

```
class PlasticForStackViews: UIStackView, SomeProto {
  //.. copy and paste in the identical code.
  //.. if I edit something in one, edit in both
}
```

Note that you can't compose (unless I drastically misunderstand something, tell me if I'm wrong) any of the good stuff in the UIView classes, layoutSubviews etc.

(Obviously if the issue at hand is just "adding corners" or such you can usually trivially use an extension).

*(Note that this does assume the various issues addressed in the "base class" do apply to both UIView and the other view types, stack view in the example. Obviously you couldn't generalize something specific to, say, an image view, across a "similar base class" for the other view types.)*

Is there a solution to this problem?

The problem at hand is completely different from a protocol solution, because, in fact, you can't compose (unless I drastically misunderstand something, tell me if I'm wrong) any of the good stuff in the UIView classes ... layoutSubviews etc.

Comment: Just in case this is not a random name that doesn't mean anything - what is "bringup stuff"?

Comment: It's a little difficult to discuss so abstractly, but the key tool will be composition rather than inheritance. Move your shared code into an object (often called a "strategy") all of the types *use* rather than a class all the types *are*. (Think about how you would solve this problem in a language that doesn't have subclassing at all.)

Comment: @Sweeper it's an example of code you want to run when the view first appears, "bring-up code"

Comment: hi @RobNapier sure, but unless I misunderstand something, that's unfortunately the whole point. In Swift (UIKit in particular) one can't compose layoutSubviews (unless I misunderstand something) and you can't compose overrides. Sorry, I thought it was evident that was the nature of the question - I'll edit!  There's the similar infuriation in UIKit that one can't (unless I misunderstand something) compose touch handling in VCs; if you write a beautiful system for touch handling something, there's no way to "apply it to" any VC.

Comment: By composing, I mean you'll call the strategy object's methods to do whatever logic you want to apply. For touch handling, those strategy objects definitely exist and are built-in. They're UIGestureRecognizers. For `layoutSubviews`, you would override that method and pass the view hierarchy to the strategy object to be laid out. It's not magically applied with mixins and diamond patterns, but it also doesn't have the headaches of conflicting mixins and diamond patterns.... All the code and logic, though, can definitely be reused without copy and paste.

Comment: This question is not about UIKit. It's only about using protocol extensions for overriding. I'm surprised that there doesn't seem to be a duplicate question for that, but although UIKit is the most common use case, it's not special.

Comment: (Note that all the UIKit patterns only can use things that are possible in Objective-C. SwiftUI applies radically different patterns since it's Swift-only.)

Comment: @Jessy I guess one would say yes in theory but the `pre_plastic_layoutSubviews` `post_ plastic_layoutSubviews` thing, for me, makes it not usable in real-world projects.

Answer (score 0):

You say

> It's completely different from a protocol

but this is a description of protocol extensions:

> many of the features of the various view classes are identical and can be handled identically

If you need "overrides" of default implementations, put the declarations in the protocol definition. Otherwise, don't bother.

```swift
protocol PlasticProtocol: UIView {
  func something() -> String
}

// MARK: - internal
extension PlasticProtocol {
  func etc() {
    // …
  }

  func something() -> String {
    "default"
  }

  func variousBringupStuff() {
    // …
  }
}
```

```swift
// MARK: - PlasticProtocol
extension Plastic: PlasticProtocol {
  func something() -> String {
    "override"
  }
}
```

```swift
let plastic = Plastic()
plastic.something() // override
let plasticProtocol: some PlasticProtocol = plastic
plasticProtocol.something() // default
```

Naming is going to be terrible, when you need to override superclass members. And you'll still need to define the overrides and call `super`. But that's better than copypasta.

```swift
// MARK: - UIView
extension Plastic {
  override func layoutSubviews() {
    plastic_layoutSubviews()
    super.layoutSubviews()
  }
}
```

```swift
// MARK: - UIView
extension PlasticProtocol {
  func plastic_layoutSubviews() {
    // …
  }
}
```

Comment: hi Jessy, thanks. Indeed I am only talking about the "bits one can't compose" like layoutSubviews and overrides.  (I removed the trivial examples of "common functions" from the question.)  It sounds like you're basically saying **it can't be done** in swift, so I guess that's that. One note, regarding your example of overriding layoutSubviews, unfortunately I've found that cure to be worse than the problem you know :/  (Just one shitty issue is you usually need "pre and post super" versions!) TY

Comment: @Fattie have you though about making your `Plastic` class generic? Along the lines of `Plastic<View: UIView>: UIView` and then you can create `UIView` subclass specific types of it, such as `Plastic<UIStackView>`, etc.

Comment: what a great idea @DávidPásztor  i'm not sure how that would help with eg. `layoutSubviews` but i'll go investigate !